# Filenames without extension, check if they are gzipped files or gzipped tar files

Tags: gzip, tar, gunzip

I have a list of very big files, some files are gzipped tarfiles, while others are only compressed gzip-files. Unfortunately, they all got the extension .gz. Is there an easy way to check which files should actually have the .tar.gz extension without unpacking and repacking all the files?

Comment: the way you ask this it's merely a usage, not a programming question. However, have you heard of the `file` utility that comes with most unixoid systems? It does exactly that, test files against a set of known signatures. anyway, in your case, using gzip or really, just looking for the gzip header bits (this is all well-documented, if you just google for it) would also do the job... Go, and research!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I only now the very basics of unix. I have googled for half an hour, but couldn't find the results and am continuing checking the files one by one. I have tried the file-command, but it just says that all files are  gzip compressed data. When I use the head-command I get unreadable header bits (e.g. :RS▒▒K▒▒H▒,▒▒q▒▒▒_UWu}▒▒▒▒A▒d▒kP)ݙp5). I now just type for each file 'tar -xzvf filename' if it works I suppose it is a tar.gz file, if I get an error I suppose it is a real .gz-file.

Comment: of course you can't read the files as if they're plaintext – they're not! But by just uncompressing the first let's say 512 B (which is really *nothing* for a modern computer), and then looking at the bits that say whether something is a .tar file, you'd solve this in an instant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I googled 12 minutes more and found the zcat command which resolves my problem. Half of the files give a readable output, while the other half is not readable.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to decompress the first 512 bytes of each gzip file. Compute the tar checksum for that header, and see if it matches the checksum in the header at offset 148. Due to some inconsistency in historical implementations of tar, you'll need to do the calculation two ways. See this note from the tar wikipedia page:

> The checksum is calculated by taking the sum of the unsigned byte
>   values of the header record with the eight checksum bytes taken to be
>   ascii spaces (decimal value 32). It is stored as a six digit octal
>   number with leading zeroes followed by a NUL and then a space. Various
>   implementations do not adhere to this format. For better
>   compatibility, ignore leading and trailing whitespace, and take the
>   first six digits. In addition, some historic tar implementations
>   treated bytes as signed. Implementations typically calculate the
>   checksum both ways, and treat it as good if either the signed or
>   unsigned sum matches the included checksum.

If the checksum matches, then it is very likely that you have a .tar.gz file. If the checksum does not match, then it is not a .tar.gz file.

Also it could be an empty tar file if it decompresses to 1024 bytes in total, and the bytes are all zeros.